# How to get Index(Rank) from record (with given condition) in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am fetching data with `aggregate()`, and it's working fine. I am using collection `sentimentAnalysisYTD` and data in this collection :

```
{
  "_id": "60d1c3a13bef1b1c92361313",
  "review_id": "6168476",
  "id": "20143",
  "posted_date": "2021-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
  "user_rating": 10,
  "user_id": "111410796",
  "ota": "klook",
  "source_market": "en_sg",
  "createdAt": "2021-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
  "sentiment_class": 2,
  "sentiment_score": 0.998403429985046,
  "persona": [
    "food & drink critic"
  ]
}
```

And now I have to get the Rank of my product (which is `id` as `product_id`, I will match with given `product_id`). Also, I am using `$limit` and `$offset`. How can I get my current rank with given `product_id`. I have tried the following code :

```
database.collection("productsSingleDayData").createIndex({ id: -1 })

database.collection("sentimentAnalysisYTD").aggregate([
    {
        $match: condition
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "productsSingleDayData",
            localField: "id",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "product_details"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$product_details"
    },
    {
        "$group":
        {
            _id:
            {
                "id": "$id"
            },
            csat: { "$avg": { "$ifNull": ["$user_rating", 0] } },
            product_details: {
                $first: "$product_details"
            },
            // topusers: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            totalPositiveScores: {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [{
                        "$eq": ["$sentiment_class", 2]
                    }, "$sentiment_score", 0]
                }
            },
            totalNegativeScores: {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [{
                        "$eq": ["$sentiment_class", 0]
                    }, "$sentiment_score", 0]
                }
            },
            totalNeturalScores: {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [{
                        "$eq": ["$sentiment_class", 1]
                    }, "$sentiment_score", 0]
                }
            },
            total_positive:
            {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $and: [
                            { "$eq": ["$sentiment_class", 2] }
                            /*{"$eq":["$sentiment_class","negative"]  }*/

                        ]
                    },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }

            },

            total_negative:

            {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $and: [
                            { "$eq": ["$sentiment_class", 0] }
                        ]
                    },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }

            },

            total_netural:

            {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $and: [
                            { "$eq": ["$sentiment_class", 1] }
                        ]
                    },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }

            },
            total_reviews:

            {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $and: [

                        ]
                    },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }

            },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            'totalPositiveScores': 1,
            'totalNegativeScores': 1,
            'total_positive': 1,
            'total_netural': 1,
            'total_negative': 1,
            'total_reviews': 1,
            "product_details": 1,
            "rank": 1,
            'average_positive_score': {
                $cond: [{
                    $gt: ["$total_positive", 0]
                }, {
                    $divide: ["$totalPositiveScores", "$total_positive"]
                }, 0]
            },
            'average_negative_score': {
                $cond: [{
                    $gt: ["$total_negative", 0]
                }, {
                    $divide: ["$totalNegativeScores", "$total_negative"]
                }, 0]
            },
            'average_netural_score': {
                $cond: [{
                    $gt: ["$total_netural", 0]
                }, {
                    $divide: ["$totalNeturalScores", "$total_netural"]
                }, 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            [req.body.sentiment_class]: -1,
        }
    },
    {
        $skip: parseInt(req.body.offset)
    },
    {
        $limit: parseInt(req.body.limit)
    },
])
```

Comment: How do you want to get the rank? you want to calculate it, your question is not clear can you please elaborate.

Comment: @turivishal. Suppose there is 100 products I got. And i have selected my particular product and it is coming on like 70 position and this position is a Rank.

Comment: @turivishal the problem is i added $limit and $skip. It giving only 10 products.

Comment: *the problem is i added $limit and $skip. It gives only 10 products*, => actually that is a feature you are using to limit your result. I don't think it's a problem. and I think its really not a good idea to generate rank from mongodb query, it will reduce the performance of query, and it is better if you generate and show rank in client side.

Comment: Thats the problem. If my current product index is 577 and its difficult to get data with these records. i have 5.5 million record in database.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get the product by virtual rank. you can pre save the rank in the product document.